# Sorting by Month in delphi

Tags: delphi, ms-access-2007

I am using Delphi 7 and Ms access 2007. I have a table called IndividualAccounts with the following field names in Ms access: Serial number, names, month paid, year paid. I have the following code to generate a report on a specific serial number I input.

```
procedure TReportsForm.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  qry :string;
begin
  open;
  SQL.Clear;
  qry:= 'select*from IndividualAccount WHERE (((IndividualAccount.[Serial Number])=1))ORDER BY IndividualAccount.[Year Paid]';
  SQL.Add(qry);
  Active:= True;
  reportform1.QuickRep1.Preview;
end;
```

I want to sort the report according to the calendar month order that is from January to December and year paid. What code can I add above to generate a report which orders the months in calendar order?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Delphi. It's strictly an Access SQL question. Your Delphi code is irrelevant to the question being asked. It's also difficult to answer, because the column names are meaningless without also knowing the data type of the column. The answer is different if *month paid* is the textual name of the month (January, February) or it's an integer value from 1-12.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `month paid` and `year paid` columns are numbers and not strings, your query would need to look like this:

```
qry := 'SELECT * FROM IndividualAccount WHERE ((IndividualAccount.[Serial Number]) = 1) ORDER BY IndividualAccount.[Year Paid], IndividualAccount.[Month Paid]';
```

The rows will be sorted by `year paid` first, and then any rows that have the same year will be sorted by `month paid`.

A better solution would be to change the database to have a new `date paid` column that uses SQL's `DATETIME` date type.  If you don't want to lose the existing `month paid` and `year paid` columns, you could create `date paid` as a *calculated column* that returns a `DATETIME` value calculated from the `month paid` and `year paid` column values using SQL's `DateSerial()` function (or change the `month paid` and `year paid` columns into *calculated columns* that use SQL's `DatePart()` or `Month()`/`Year()` functions to pull apart the value of the `date paid` column).  Then you can sort rows in calendar order by sorting on the `date paid` column by itself:

```
qry := 'SELECT * FROM IndividualAccount WHERE ((IndividualAccount.[Serial Number]) = 1) ORDER BY IndividualAccount.[Date Paid]';
```